# Is it poor practice to host multiple web applications on the same domain, in terms of cookies?

Tags: cookies

In my web application, I have a single API backend and two frontends written as single page applications. To simplify deployment, I'd like to serve the API on `/api`, the admin dashboard on `/admin`, and the end user frontend on `/user` (or something similar), all on the same domain.

I want to use cookies for handling sessions, for both the end-user and admin apps. Is this a good idea? As I understand it, cookie usage is restricted by their domain. Would it make it simpler for an attacker to steal admin-session cookies from someone logged into both frontends? Or, should I use different domains for the admin and user frontends (admin.mydomain.com and user.mydomain.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies can be also restricted by the URL path. In this case you can use the `Path` attribute in the session cookie:

> Path attribute
>
> The Path attribute indicates a URL path that must exist in the requested URL in order to send the Cookie header. The %x2F ("/") character is considered a directory separator, and subdirectories match as well.
> For example, if Path=/docs is set, these paths match:
>
> /docs
>
> /docs/Web/
>
> /docs/Web/HTTP

For the sessions, it's better to have two different ones:

- one for the admin endpoint (Path = /admin)
- one for the user endpoint (Path = /user)

This will prevent privileges escalation (vertical).

To prevent stealing the cookie, you can add the attributes:

- HttpOnly: prevent access to cookie values via javascript
- Secure: ensure that cookies are sent securely and are not accessed by unintended parties
- SameSite: Protect against CSRF

Finally, make sure that your application does not have any XSS vulnerability. You can find more details about how to prevent of it on:

- https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html
- https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/53189097.pdf
- https://www.ukessays.com/essays/computer-science/prevention-of-cross-site-scripting-attacks.php

Hope it answer your question.

**source:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies